# Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Windows Phone Stack Exchange](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why am I not able to switch-off my Windows Phone while it is charging?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3181/why-am-i-not-able-to-switch-off-my-windows-phone-while-it-is-charging)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Uneditable Word Document](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/uneditable-word-document)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to pin the battery saver to the start menu?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3246/how-to-pin-the-battery-saver-to-the-start-menu)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to stop downloading app updates when connected in Mobile data?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/how-to-stop-downloading-app-updates-when-connected-in-mobile-data)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Are background tasks needed for push notifications to work?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3297/are-background-tasks-needed-for-push-notifications-to-work)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Android Apps in WindowsPhone 8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/android-apps-in-windowsphone-8)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [No Outlook emails in my Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3186/no-outlook-emails-in-my-windows-phone)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Change where deleted emails go?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/change-where-deleted-emails-go)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Watching movies on internet](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/watching-movies-on-internet)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Is it possible to migrate WiFi settings from one phone to another?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3237/is-it-possible-to-migrate-wifi-settings-from-one-phone-to-another)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---